# How to use `ggplot2`'s functions without loading the package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using `ggplot2`, sometimes we need to use multiple functions in order to plot data:

```
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = .data$drv)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

An alternative way to do this plot without loading the whole `ggplot2` package would be:

```
p <-ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::mpg) + 
   ggplot2::geom_bar(ggplot2::aes(x = .data$drv)) + 
   ggplot2::coord_flip()
```

How can we do this plot without having to load the package throught `library("ggplot2")`, or having to write `ggplot2::` for every function?

Comment: I saw somewhere where `if()else{}` or `ifelse()` (I not sure, tho) was used to this end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withr::with_package` temporarily loads a package.

```
p <- withr::with_package("ggplot2", {
  ggplot(mpg) + 
    geom_bar(aes(x = drv)) + 
    coord_flip()
})
```